# php-fpm chroot setup with apache mod_proxy_fcgi

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, mod-proxy-fcgi

i'm looking for recent instructions on how to set up apache with mod_proxy_fcgi and chrooted php-fpm. i was successful for the whole process except for the chroot part. i'm trying to use the most advanced setup, to me this is the "Proxy via Handler" method using a unix domain socket as described on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html. i'm not posting any config details, just asking for any generic instructions or examples on how to do this (my error is of course "AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'").

all i could find are instructions for nginx, apache with mod_fastcgi, etc.

thx for any hints